# How to create many frequency tables with percentage columns using specific variables combinations in a simple way?

Tags: r, dataframe, datatables, frequency, percentage

I have this dataframe (let's imagine it has tens of variables)

```
set.seed(505)
df = data.frame(age_group = c(1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,2,1,2,3),
                score = trunc(runif(17,0,5)),
                sex = trunc(runif(17,0,2)),
                FO1 = trunc(runif(17,0,2)),
                FN2 = trunc(runif(17,0,2)),
                AL3 = trunc(runif(17,0,2)),
                PM4 = trunc(runif(17,0,2)))
```

I want to create many frequency tables with their percentages. The tables include combinations of each FO1 , FN2 , AL3 , PM4 and each of age_group and score variables (**without the sex variable**). for example : `table(df$FO1 ,df$age_group)` or `table(df$FO1 ,df$score)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one simple solution could be looping like this and using 'prop.table()':

```
cols1 <- c("FO1", "FN2", "AL3", "PM4")
cols2 <- c("age_group", "score")

for (i in cols1) {
  for (j in cols2) {
    cat(paste0("i = ", i, ", j = ", j, ":\n"))
    print(prop.table(table(df[, i], df[, j])))
    cat("\n")
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!
Samuel